# mysqli_real_connect()(HY000/1130)Host 'localhost'is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Yesterday  my MySQL was working fine. Today I try to access it and I get the above error. i have tried a few suggestions from here but no change. Keep getting 'localhost' is not allowed to connect.....
Checked the config.inc.php file

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

Looks OK to me but I am no more than a beginner

and the error log below makes no sense to me

```
    2020-07-27 19:33:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=17995039
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 17995048; transaction id 2579
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-27 19:33:46 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-07-27 19:33:47 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table 'user' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-07-27 19:33:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200727 19:33:48
2020-07-27 19:33:48 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-07-27 19:33:48 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-07-27 19:33:48 0 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.16-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2020-07-27 19:36:55 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2020-07-27 19:36:55 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2020-07-27 19:36:55 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-07-27 19:36:55 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-07-27 19:36:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-27 19:36:55 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2020-07-27 19:36:55 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Thanks for any info.

Comment: First try to run the following command: mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases

Answer (score 0):

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
```

That implies that you were not 'root' when you installed MySQL.